# Find which element is the max for python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to merge two sorted Linked Lists. I want to assign the root to be the larger of the two heads. How do I know which element is the max so I can increment it to the next node?

Currently I am using this code

`root = ListNode(max(l1.val, l2.val))`

Comment: Try `max(l1, l2, key=lambda x: x.val)`.  Here, `max` returns whichever of `l1` and `l2` has the highest value when sent to the lambda function, which just looks at their `val` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `max` with a key:

```
root = ListNode(max(l1, l2, key=lambda x: x.val).val)
```

The `max` function will return the node with the highest value when used passed this `key`.

Alternatively, you can use `operator.attrgetter`:

```
import operator
root = ListNode(max(l1, l2, key=operator.attrgetter('val')).val)
```